# How can I block ~ symbol when I'm on /home/user directory?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, directory, prompt

I want to block `~` symbol when I'm in `/home/user` directory. I want this because I'm trying to make my Linux system look like Windows 10.

My current prompt look like

```
C:~/>
```

I want to make it look like

```
C:/home/user/>
```

Comment: What is `C:`? Is that ever supposed to change? If yes, how? Also, have a look at [Bash prompt customization](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization).

Comment: C: is drive label like in Windows but does nothing.

Comment: "_I'm trying to make my Linux system look like Windows 10_" Linux-based systems aren't Windows systems. They obviously have similarities but there are many differences. Trying to make one look like the other can, at best, be a superficial exercise

Comment: You just need to find the right content to put into your PS1 variable (you could re-define it inside ~/.bashrc to suit your needs). try for exemple (within the shell, and when it looks perfect insert it into your ~/.bashrc)  : `PS1='\u@\h:\w # '`

Answer (score 2):

You can set PS1 as

```
PS1='C:$PWD>'
```

`$PWD` is expanded to the current working directory.

Add that line to `~/.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: I know it too, but when I go to a new directory, its not works.
Prompt like:
C:/home/user/Documents/> cd ..
and prompt still like:
C:/home/user/Documents/>

Comment: @maDev If you knew that, you could have added it to the question so as to avoid an answer that you already know does not work. Now, what you describe shouldn't be happening. Is `PS1='C:$(pwd)>'` any better?

Comment: @maDev It's important that you use single quotes exactly as shown in the answer. If the prompt isn't changing when you use `cd`, this means you've either used double quotes or no quotes at all.

Comment: ? Single quotes and double quotes are same. They are both string

Comment: @maDev They are not. Single quotes suppress expansion of shell variables, double quotes don't. In your case, you obviously used double quotes so the `$PWD` was resolved to the "current directory" when the `.bashrc` was processed, and the result of that resolution - a fixed string representing the current directory _at the time of shell startup_ - was set as command prompt. You need to use single quotes, so that the command prompt is set _literally_ to `$PWD` which is then interpreted "on-the-fly" by the shell to reflect the current directory _at the time of displaying the prompt_.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://superuser.com/a/232726/332907)

```
export PS1='C:$(pwd)> '
```

If it works for you, add it to your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc`

Comment: Dude PS1 not working, when I use PS! it not gets updated when I change directory

Comment: @maDev what _exactly_ did you type to set the `PS1` prompt? Also, is there any result from running `set | grep PROMPT`?